# Passing row data to custom buttons on pipeline datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

all i'm trying to do so far is display row data with window.alert at the click of a custom button on each table row. But so far i have not been able too.
here is my code:

```
    $.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
        // Configuration options
        var conf = $.extend( {
            pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
            url: '',      // script url
            data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                          // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
            method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
        }, opts );

        // Private variables for storing the cache
        var cacheLower = -1;
        var cacheUpper = null;
        var cacheLastRequest = null;
        var cacheLastJson = null;

        return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
            var ajax          = false;
            var requestStart  = request.start;
            var drawStart     = request.start;
            var requestLength = request.length;
            var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;

            if ( settings.clearCache ) {
                // API requested that the cache be cleared
                ajax = true;
                settings.clearCache = false;
            }
            else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
                // outside cached data - need to make a request
                ajax = true;
            }
            else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                      JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                      JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
            ) {
                // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
                ajax = true;
            }

            // Store the request for checking next time around
            cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );

            if ( ajax ) {
                // Need data from the server
                if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                    requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));

                    if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                        requestStart = 0;
                    }
                }

                cacheLower = requestStart;
                cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);

                request.start = requestStart;
                request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;

                // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
                if ( $.isFunction ( conf.data ) ) {
                    // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                    // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                    // data object to submit
                    var d = conf.data( request );
                    if ( d ) {
                        $.extend( request, d );
                    }
                }
                else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                    // As an object, the data given extends the default
                    $.extend( request, conf.data );
                }

                settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                    "type":     conf.method,
                    "url":      conf.url,
                    "data":     request,
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "cache":    false,
                    "success":  function ( json ) {
                        cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);

                        if ( cacheLower != drawStart ) {
                            json.data.splice( 0, drawStart-cacheLower );
                        }
                        if ( requestLength >= -1 ) {
                            json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );
                        }

                        drawCallback( json );
                    }
                } );
            }
            else {
                json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
                json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
                json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
                json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

                drawCallback(json);
            }
        };
    };

    // Register an API method that will empty the pipelined data, forcing an Ajax
    // fetch on the next draw (i.e. `table.clearPipeline().draw()`)
    $.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
        return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
            settings.clearCache = true;
        } );
    } );


    //
    // DataTables initialisation
    //
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#first_cycle').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
     url: 'scripts/server_processing.php',
     pages: 5 // number of pages to cache
    }),

    "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": -1,
    "data": null,
    "defaultContent": "
<div class='w3-btn-group w3-vertical w3-row-padding'>
<a id='payment' >click1</a>
<button id='paymentDetails' >click2</button></div>"
     }]
     } );

    $('#first_cycle tbody').on( 'click', '#paymentDetails', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    window.alert( data[1] );
    } );


    });
```

This fetches the table quite alright but the part i can't seem to get right is this part

```
 $('#first_cycle tbody').on( 'click', '#paymentDetails', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    window.alert( data[1] );
    } );
```

and i made sure to include all of this

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

but it's still not working, i'll be really glad if anyone can help me out.

Comment: What's the error? does the event handler actually run but the alert shows the wrong result or the handler doesn't even run?

Comment: table undefined

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comment, it seems that you forgot to assign the `table` variable to the Datatable's instance.

try declaring table as global (`var table` at the beginning of the script, so you can access it everywhere) and assign the DataTable's instance to it:

```
table = $("#first_cycle").DataTable({...});
```

Comment: great, glad to help!